# C# how to check if string contains a string combine with changeable value

Tags: c#, string, filtering

Currently I'm writing:

```
    string[] ReadText = File.ReadAllLines(_FILE);
    for(int idx = 0; idx < ReadText.Length; idx++)
    {
        if (ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK0")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK1")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK2")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK3")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK4")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK5")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK6")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK7")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK8")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK9")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK10")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK11")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK12")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK13")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK14")
        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK15")
        || etc.)
    }
```

It's terrible if i want to check from BANK0 to BANK255.
Is there a method like:

```
    if (ReadText[idx].Contains(string.format("BANK{0}",[0-255]))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for regex

Comment: Do you care which line number or d you just want the lines where the 'xxxx' appears?

Comment: Might just be easier to go with something like `Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(i => "BANK" + i).Contains(ReadText[idx])` than regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Regex` can help you:

```
//this will match exact the BANKx to BANK255
var isMatch = Regex.Matches(ReadText[idx], "BANK([12]([0-4]\\d|5[0-5])|\\d{1,2})").Count > 0;
//then check for if(isMatch) ...
```

If there is no restriction to the `xxx` in `BANKxxx` (for example, `BANK555` is OK), we can use a simpler pattern:

```
var isMatch = Regex.Matches(ReadText[idx], "BANK\\d+").Count > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with Regex. It feels like your method is what i want.

Comment: You can also use capture group + regex, and check if that captured value is within the range you want, because honestly regex is a poor solution for arithmetical comparison.

Comment: @Alwyn of course that's a good solution, but it requires some `for` loop to loop through all the groups and `parse` the values into `int` or `float`... to check the values against some criteria. This way we don't need any `for` loop. Of course this way is limited in ability to check numeric values but it's OK for this case of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function like this will work:

```
Private Function strContains(input As String) As Boolean
    If input.Contains("Bank") Then
        Dim temp As Integer = -1
        If Integer.TryParse(input.Substring(4), temp) AndAlso temp > -1 Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function

If strContains(ReadText[idx]) Then

End If
```